# TMS/Web8.5 Support bundle added multilple Components/Pages translations

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager

My testing team created new bundle and added four new components in SDL Web 8.5 CMS. Bundle send to translation and translation completed. The issue is Bundle retrieving failed.

If we send the component/page to translation and retrieving  properly.

I want to know TMS/SDL Web8.5 support bundle With multiple components/pages translations.

looking for Suggestions and Solutions for this issue.